# THREE.CanvasRenderer rendering issue, circles leave a 'trace' even though setClearColor is set

Tags: three.js

This has been puzzling me all day. I have put together a very simple holding page for [a website that can be viewed here](http://designs.digital/). It has a very simple three.js animated scene as a background. This is based on one of the examples. Then the user moves the mouse to the top of the window the animation responds to the input. The issue is that there seems to be rendering artefact (see image below or try online in above link)

[image: Example screenshot of three.js rendering issue]

It seems that there is an unwanted 'trace' like effect that I just can't seem to prevent. The clear color is set 'renderer.setClearColor(0xEFEFEF, 1). I have tried 'renderer.autoClear = true' explicitly but still the artefacts show. It seems to happen when the circle is at the very edge of the drawn area when moving vertically.

I have tried searching everywhere but failed to find an answer. Can anyone help?

UPDATE:

I looked at the [link provided by WestLangley](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/355) where the context.arc scaling looked like a possible cause. It turned out that it was not. I was using a value < 1. I tried a value 1 but the artefacts still show.

I believe that since the drawing area changes each frame (due to the sinusoidal nature of the wave animation) and the changing viewing angle of the camera, the area that is cleared is incorrect. The drawing area that is cleared is the drawing  area of the current frame (to be rendered), leaving an uncleared area from the previous frame (already rendered and visible) and  possibly artefacts. This only occurs when the drawing area is shrinking and the camera is moving in the opposite direction to the reduction in drawing area. I believe, in order for these artefacts to not show, the drawing area of the previous frame should be cleared and not the area of the current frame before drawing. I am still looking at this.

UPDATE 2:

I seem to have verified the drawing area clearance theory from update 1. By adding:

```
renderer.getContext().canvas.getContext("2d").clearRect(0, 0, renderer.getContext().canvas.width, renderer.getContext().canvas.height);
```

before the renderer.render(scene, camera) call, the entire canvas was cleared to white. Since the renderer.setClearColor(0xEFEFEF, 1) is set to slightly off-white, one can clearly see the drawing area.

I decided to add a plane with a transparent material to force the drawing area to be full size of the canvas. I am not 100% happy with this but it seems to be a workaround.

```
var geo = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(1920 * 2, 1080 * 2, 1, 1);
var mat = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ opacity: 0.01 });
var plane = new THREE.Mesh(geo, mat);
```

The artefacts are banished.

Comment: I have tried your page and there is no artifact on my browser (Chrome on Win x64, GPU AMD HD 5700). I am not sure how much is CanvasRenderer sensitive to driver bugs, but perhaps you could try updating a driver, or testing on a different computer? - Correction: I see it now, it appeared after testing a bit longer.

Comment: FWIW, these issues have come up [before](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/355).

Comment: Do you still have a link to the version that was leaving trails?

Comment: [mrdoob](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1137134/mrdoob) I have [uploaded a version temporarily here](http://designs.digital/mrdoob) for you to see. No way to message/email.

Comment: @mrdoob http://designs.digital/mrdoob

Comment: I can reproduce. I'll take a look.

Comment: Ok great, I am really interested to know what is going on.

Comment: Actually, do you mind creating a jsfiddle with the effect? It'll help me a lot.

Comment: @mrdoob [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z03qh6Lz/3/)

It is a cut and paste but it shows the issue.

Comment: @mrdoob Simpler fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/z03qh6Lz/4/

Comment: @mrdoob https://jsfiddle.net/z03qh6Lz/5/  Added line 106 to highlight the draw area (as in update 2 above). Is there a way to see this within three.js? (some debug mode or similar?)

Comment: 1/sqrt(2) appears to be the max radius for the arc to prevent the bug. Compensate by scaling `particle.scale` by sqrt(2). https://jsfiddle.net/z03qh6Lz/6/ Not sure why this particular value is the limit, or why the bug appears to be intermittant.

Comment: @WestLangley Reducing the particle size does prevent the issue but I do not think this is an acceptable answer as it forces me to use smaller particles which I do not want. There seems to be an issue with the draw area clearance. I assume the whole canvas is not cleared and redrawn as an optimization. I would rather force the redraw area size to be larger and maintain aesthetic than be forced change the look. Both these seem to be workarounds.

Comment: (1) I did not say this workaround was a solution. (2) The workaround is not rendering smaller particles because you compensate by increasing the scale. (3) If you don't want to modify your code, an alternative is to modify `CanvasRenderer.js` line 520 like so: `var dist = 1.42 * 0.5 * Math.sqrt( scaleX * scaleX + scaleY * scaleY ); // allow for rotated sprite`.

Comment: @WestLangley Firstly, I appreciate the input and help. I did assume a little. However, the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z03qh6Lz/6) you posted still has the same artefacts, just much reduced. I already have a 100% solid workaround that I have been using (update 2). I am just interested in knowing what causes this effect and if it is indeed related to the drawing area as I hypothesised in the original post. I am not looking to change values arbitrarily to prevent the effect. I wish understand this strange thing I seem to have stumbled upon. I hope you understand my reasoning. Thanks.

Comment: You are not understanding what I am trying to tell you. You do not have to change any of your code. You can make the change to the formula for `dist` in your local copy of `CanvasRenderer.js`. If that does not prevent the artifacts, then let me know. The last fiddle I posted has no artifacts when I run it. I am surprised to hear it has artifacts for you.

Comment: @mrdoob I think the change required to `CavasRenderer` is `var dist = 1.00 * Math.sqrt( scaleX * scaleX + scaleY * scaleY ); // allow for rotated sprite`. This accommodates a `material.program` in which the entire 2 x 2 block is used, and the sprite is rotated 45 degrees -- the worst case. Three years ago when we discussed this, I was assuming the block was 1 x 1.

Comment: @WestLangley I understand precisely what you are saying. Do not say otherwise. Your [jsfiddle did not remove artifacts](https://s28.postimg.org/517j116wb/z03qh6_Lz_6.png). It did reduce them, but it is irrelevant since I already had a 100% workaround. I do not want to make changes to the three.js source (CanvasRenderer.js) either. My aim was: "I wish understand this strange thing I seem to have stumbled upon. I hope you understand my reasoning. Thanks."

Comment: _elemBox is a THREE.Box2 that has the bounds of the element in question (later used _clearBox.union( _elemBox )).
As @WestLangley stated earlier the 'dist' was calculated in a way that returned a value to small. Changing it to: 'var dist = Math.sqrt(scaleX * scaleX + scaleY * scaleY);' [does seem to work, but only whilst the arc of the material program is < 1](https://s10.postimg.org/mzo31kbvb/modified_test.png). Make the arc value 2 tracing returns. The clearance calculations seem to to have no knowledge of the underlying material program dimensions. An arbitrary limit seems to be required.

Comment: Yes, the constraint on the drawing area was [stated](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/355#issuecomment-27069154) by mrdoob in the original link I posted. Also, by me, [here](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/4178#issuecomment-29952578). The original bug fix can be found [here](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/pull/4144). There was a misunderstanding regarding the material program drawing limits.

Comment: @WestLangley I see, thanks... So currently, CanvasRenderer line 529 (var dist = 0.5 * Math.sqrt.....) is broken even when arc <= 1. When line 529 is changed to 'var dist = Math.sqrt( scaleX * scaleX + scaleY * scaleY );' all is fixed. Currently there is a bug in the CanvasRenderer? Boundary case?

Comment: Yes, currently there is a bug if the program is allowed to draw inside a 2x2 square. The worse case is when the program is `program: function( context ) { context.fillStyle = "#FFFF00"; context.fillRect( - 1, - 1, 2, 2 ); }` and `particle.material.rotation = Math.PI / 4;`. If the understanding is the program is allowed to draw only in a 1x1 square, then there is no bug.

Comment: This has now been [fixed](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/pull/10999) in three.js r85.dev.